# Search filter laravel problem with get values from

Tags: php, laravel

My Controller:

```
public function FilteredAdsShow(){

    $id= Input::get('category'); //get id from select name="categories"
    $tit = Input::get('titleFilter'); // get title from input text
    $categories = Category::all();

    $ads = Ad::where('category_id','=',$id)
        ->where('active','=',1)
        ->where('title','=',$tit)
        ->orderby('promoted','1')
        ->orderby('created_at','desc')
        ->with('images')
        ->get();

    return view('filtered')
        ->with(compact('ads'))
        ->with(compact('categories'));

}
```

I have a button on my view that calls a route when it is clicked.
I am doing a foreach too to get all values that has that title and where category_id = $id but it's not working.

View:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('search')
    @include('pieces.search')
@endsection

    @foreach($ads as $ad)
        <div class="col-3 adSection">
            <img src="{{$ad->images->first()->path}}" alt="Imagem do anuncio" class="adImages"/>
            <p>{{$ad->title}}</p>
            <p>{{$ad->price}}</p>
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

My search components are on my search view i'm including.

View I call my search view:

> @section('search')
>       @include('pieces.search') @endsection
>
> ```
> @foreach($ads as $ad)
>     <div class="col-3 adSection">
>         <img src="{{$ad->images->first()->path}}" alt="Imagem do anuncio" class="adImages"/>
>         <p>{{$ad->title}}</p>
>         <p>{{$ad->price}}</p>
>     </div>
> @endforeach
> ```

And my route:

```
Route::get('/filteredAds','MainController@FilteredAdsShow')->name('filteredAds');
```

My search view:

```
<div class="col-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="titleFilter" placeholder="Pesquise pelo título" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="category">
            <option value="-1">Todos</option>
            @foreach($categories as $category )
                <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="col-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <a href="{{route('filteredAds')}}" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Pesquisar</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use `dd(Input::get('category'));` in controller method to see what is coming from front-end

Comment: Show your route and blade file from where you are sending filters to controller

Comment: is returning null

Comment: my route: Route::get('/filteredAds','MainController@FilteredAdsShow')->name('filteredAds');

Comment: update your question and add route and blade file where you are applying search filters

Comment: Done Afraz, you can check now

Comment: where is select with name category ?

Comment: and where is the button which is triggering route call <

Comment: check the question because I put the code of search view there

Comment: Problem is in your anchor tag. your anchor tag is just calling a route but it is not sending any value to controller.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your **anchor tag**. your anchor tag is just calling a route but it is **not sending any value to controller**

To send selected option value to controller you will have to use jquery.

1. get title value

**HTML**:

Input tag having some id

```
    <input type="text" id="titleFilter" name="titleFilter" placeholder="Pesquise pelo título" class="form-control">
```

**Jquery**

```
    var titleFilter = $('#titleFilter').val();
```

2. get selected value

suppose your select has id categories

```
<select class="form-control" name="category" id='categories'> ...</select>

$('#categories').on('change',function(){
   //get selected category
   var selectedOption = $('#categories:selected').val()  
   //trigger click here to your route
});
```

3.trigger click on button when you change dropdown or however you want

Comment: the name of my select is 'category'